# How to upload custom metrics and metrics data on azure that can be seen on Azure Management Portal in Diagnostics Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am working on an application with requirement of insert/upload data on azure that can be seen on Azure Management Portal in Diagnostics Monitor/dashboard 
that shows performance counter data in form of graphs, charts.

1. I want to know how to upload data on azure.
2. How to see uploaded data in Azure Management Portal Diagnostics Monitor/dashboard (in form of graphs/charts)
3. Can this be done by creating custom metrics? If yes, how to create custom metrics and monitor? Can it be done using REST API?
4. If it is not possible to upload and view my own data on Azure Management Portal - Diagnostics Monitor (graph, chart) using custom monitor the is it possible at all to upload and view my own data in Azure Management Portal - Diagnostics Monitor/dashboard?

I am new to Azure. Please suggest if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Azure Diagnostics. The process is described here for Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines/

Comment: Thanks for the information. My requirement is like that, I need to create a custom metrics for the Virtual machine that I have created. By default it has some metrics e.g. CPU percentage, Disc Bytes Write/Sec, Network In etc. I need to create my custom metrics for the virtual machine through REST or SDK. So that the we can see the metrics chart in azure management portal for that custom metrics. Can we do the custom metrics for the Virtual machine. Not for any web app or some think like that. Is it possible in Azure? If it is possible then how can we send the data for that custom metrics?

Comment: You need to install your custom metric on the VM - perhaps through a custom script - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automating-vm-customization-tasks-using-custom-script-extension/

You would then install the diagnostics agent and configure it to persist your custom metric.

Comment: Thanks for the information, exactly I need to do is that I need to do all the operations using REST API. The operations are as follows: 1. Create Custom Metrics for the virtual machine (I guess there is a REST API to add the performance counter to WAD configuration as Create or Update Diagnostics Settings part) 2. After creating this custom metrics I need to add the data which is calculated in on-prem my application to this custom metrics at respective time interval. 3. this data should be visible in the monitor chart for the virtual machine. Can Azure do all this operations using REST API?

Comment: You can do it from PowerShell so you should be able to do it using REST. Turn on debugging and configure diagnostics using PowerShell to see the actual REST call invoked (and its properties). The REST operation is likely this one -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163624.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. Can you please let me know what kind of scripts that I will need to do for creating this custom metrics for the virtual machine? I am new to Azure so not sure about it. Is there any document for that?